# Is there any plan for ARCore to support saving and loading sparse point clouds for localisation purposes?

Tags: arcore

I'm trying to write an app for detecting "where you are" in a building use ARCore. I'd like to use previously learnt and then saved feature points to provide the initial sync position as well as then helping to continuously update position accurately. But this feature does not currently appear to be supported in ARCore.

Currently I'm using tracked images as a way to do an initial sync. It works, but not brilliantly - alignment is often a few degrees off and you have to approach the image pretty slowly and deliberately. And then once synced there is drift... Yes, loop closing works pretty well when it gets back to somewhere it recognises, but it needs to build up that map every time you start the session.

So, obvious solution: are there any plans for Google to implement "Area Learning" as it was back in Google Tango? It looks like Cloud Anchors might be some attempt to do this, but clearly that's all hosted on Google, and it strictly limited as to how long that data is stored. Currently that's just not a possible solution. OTOH, Apple's ARKit seems to now provide just what is needed:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/saving_and_loading_world_data

Does this mean that Apple / ARKit is the only way to go for the app? Hope not...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out persistent [cloud anchors](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/cloud-anchors/overview-android) that is still in development. 
From documentation:

> Note: We’re currently developing persistent Cloud Anchors, which can
>   be resolved for much longer. Before making the feature broadly
>   available, we’re looking for more developers to help us explore and
>   test persistent Cloud Anchors in real world apps at scale. [See here](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/call-for-collaborators#persistent_cloud_anchors) if
>   you’re interested.